# Unable to get property 'courseDescription' of undefined or null reference in Jquery Json example

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to build sample jquery, json example in which I have the json array variable (contains courseId, courseTitle, courseDescription). On Click of courseTitle courseDescription is to be displayed in a span. When I make hardcode reference as courseObj.courses[0].courseDescription it works but when I make courseObj.courses[i].courseDescription, 'i' being the index for iterating courses array, this gives the above error.

Can we not access content of json array dynamically inside click function. I know binding a function is static but then what's the solution?

--courseObj json array variable--

```
<script>
    var courseObj = JSON.parse('{ "courses":[{"courseId":"1001","courseTitle":"Core Java","courseDescription":"Core Java, OOPs, Multithreading, IO"},{"courseId":"1002","courseTitle":"Java Web Development","courseDescription":"Java Web Development, Servlet, JSP"}]}');                 
</script>
```

--index.html--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
              <title>JQUERY JSON SAMPLE</title>
              <meta charset="utf-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
              <script src="css/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script src="css/my_jquery_functions.js"></script>
              <script>
                    var courseObj = JSON.parse('{ "courses":[{"courseId":"1001","courseTitle":"Core Java","courseDescription":"Core Java, OOPs, Multithreading, IO"},{"courseId":"1002","courseTitle":"Java Web Development","courseDescription":"Java Web Development, Servlet, JSP"}]}');                 
              </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div>
                   <div >
                            <label id='1001'>Core Java&nbsp;</label><br><br><label id='1002'>Java Web Development&nbsp;</label><br><br>                                                                                             
                   </div>
                   <div >
                        <span id="pdesc">Program Description will be shown here on click of Program Title</span>                                            
                   </div>
             </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

--my_jquery_functions.js--

```
$(window).load(function(){
     for(var i=0;i<courseObj.courses.length;i++){
         $("#"+courseObj.courses[i].courseId).click(function(){
            //$("#pdesc").text(courseObj.courses[0].courseDescription); This line works, below line does not
             $("#pdesc").text(courseObj.courses[i].courseDescription);
         });
     }

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing it wrong way when ever click trigger , its having own click function scope where i is definitely undefined,

Whenever Click Trigger you need get the index of that  you achieve like this way

```
$(window).load(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < courseObj.courses.length; i++) {
        var courseId = courseObj.courses[i].courseId;
        $("#" + courseId).data('course_index', i);
        $("#" + courseId).click(function() {
            var course_index = $(this).data('course_index');
            $("#pdesc").text(courseObj.courses[course_index].courseDescription);
        });
    }

});
```

I preserve those index to data and whenever click trigger we retrieve current triggered index from data and get related courseDescription

Comment: Thanks, Sanjay-code you provided solved the problem.